# SQL query for a graphic chart. Not sure about how to use JOIN in this case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, highcharts

I'm trying to write an SQL query to fulfill a graphic chart, and am not sure how to do it properly.
Here's the situation.
The chart type is bar, where I want to list the 'Message Types' on the Y Axis, the 'Number of Messages' on the X Axis, and for each value on the Y Axis, create a stacked bar with the number of 'Messages' for each user in a 'Message Type'.
Something like this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked

What I want to return is:

```
SELECT COUNT(Messages.MessageId), Messages.UserName, MessageTypes.Description
```

It's really simple, but my issue is that I want to have all the possible 'MessageTypes' on the Y Axis, even if there are no 'Messages' at all linked to them (bring 0 as the COUNT in this case).

I've tried this, but it's not working:

```
FROM MessageTypes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages ON MessageTypes.MessageTypeId = Messages.MessageTypeId
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: you changed the question on me! ;)

group by description and user.name, count records, and left outer join b/t Messages and Users:

```
select
    mt.Description MessageTypeDescription
    , m.UserName -- will be null if no messages exist for a given type
    ,  UserMessageTypeCount = case when m.UserName is null then 0 else COUNT(1) end
from
    MessageTypes mt
    left outer join Messages m
     on mt.MessageTypeId = m.MessageTypeId
group by
    mt.Description
    m.UserName
```

The results will be the number of messages per message type per user

Comment: Sorry about that. I needed to change it to fit the bill. :) But I have my problem solved. Thanks, @Moho

Comment: just changed the count statement - old way would return 1 even if no messages of a type exists.  Now, if m.UserName is null, we assume the count should be 0.  if m.UserName is nullable when a message record exists, you'll have to do something else here.

Comment: I've added a WHERE to dismiss the NULL ones. Thanks! :)